# How to handle a TeX file to an Epub

Tags: epub

My goal is to create an epub file from tex (namely, an ebook with mathematical symbols).

Below is my sample code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,reqno]{amsart}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathptmx, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, mathptmx, enumerate, color}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1,T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\longrightrightarrow}%
{\scalebox{1.75}[1.15]{$\thinspace\rightrightarrows\thinspace$}}
\newcommand{\sss}{\scriptscriptstyle}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareMathOperator{\NEP}{NEP}
\newcommand\mn{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\vspace*{1.0cm}
\title[Problem]%
{Problem of TeX and Epub}
\author[D. Example, T. Epub]%
{ D. Example$^{1,*}$, T. Epub$^1$}
% Starting Date: from November 1, 2020
\maketitle
\vspace*{-0.6cm}

\begin{center}
{\footnotesize {\it
$^1$Laboratory 
}}\end{center}

\vskip 4mm {\small\noindent {\bf Abstract.}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.

\noindent {\bf Keywords.}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.

\noindent {\bf AMS Subject Classification.}
}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{}
\footnotetext{ 
$^*$Corresponding author.
\par
E-mail addresses: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
\par
Received 2021. }

\begin{example}\label{example:NEP_closedness}
    Let us suppose a \(\NEP\) for \(i\in \{1,2\}\), \(\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}\strut^{2,+}_{*}\) and \((x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\strut^{2}\). A function \(K_{i}: \mathbb{R}\strut^{+} \longrightrightarrow \mathbb{R}\) is defined as
    \begin{align*}
    K_{1}(\mu) = \left\{x :
    0 \le x \le \mu_{1}
    \right\},\quad
    %
    %
    K_{2}(\mu) = \left\{y :
    0 \le y \le \mu_{2}
    \right\}.
    \end{align*}
    Obviously, \(K_{i}(\mu)\) is nonempty and \(g_{i}: \mathbb{R}\strut^{2,+}_{*} \!\times \mathbb{R}\strut^{2} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\) defined as
    \begin{align*}
    g_{1}(\lambda,x,y) =
    h_{1}(\lambda,y) + 
    \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
    x^{2} - 1   & \textrm{if~~} 1 \le x\\
    0           & \textrm{if~~}0 \le x < 1\\
    x           & \textrm{otherwise}
    \end{array}\right.
    \end{align*}
    where \(h_{i}\) is a lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris., for all \(i\). It's clear that, for \(i = 1\) and any \((\lambda,y)\), the function \(g_{1}\) is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris in \(x\), so is for \(g_{2}\) in \(y\). And thus,
    \begin{align*}
    T_{1}(\lambda,x,y) 
    %
    &= M_{g_{1}(\lambda,\cdot,y)}^{a}(x)\backslash \{0\}
    %
    = \big\{\hat{x}\in\mathbb{R} \mid \langle \hat{x}, u - x\rangle \le 0,~ \forall u \in L_{g_{1}(\lambda,\cdot,y)}^{a}(x) \big\}\backslash \{0\}
    \end{align*}
    
    There are sequences \((\lambda_{k},\mu_{k}) \xrightarrow{\sss k\to \infty} (\lambda,\mu)\), \((x_{k},y_{k}) \xrightarrow{\sss k\to\infty} (x,y)\), then we claim
    \begin{align}
    \sup\limits_{x^{*}\in T_{1}(a,v,b)}
    \langle P^{2r}, \bar{x} - x\rangle
    %
    %
    \le \liminf\limits_{\scriptscriptstyle k\to \infty}
    %
    \sup\limits_{x_{k}^{*}\in T_{1} (d,x^{3f},m_{d})}
    \langle g_{k}^{*}, \bar{r}_{k} \! - x_{k}\rangle.
    \mn \label{eq:example_01}
    \end{align}
\end{example}

\vskip 6mm
\noindent{\bf Acknowledgments}

\noindent   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}%in appearance order.
\bibitem{1}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

From here, I use TeXstudio to compile the pdf file. It worked. Then, I use the following commands, by copying the commands to "Configure TexStudio > Build > User command", paste there and go to "Tools > User > ...".

```
code1: htlatex %.tex
```

or

```
code2: htlatex %.tex 'xhtml,charset=utf-8,pmathml' ' -cunihtf -utf8 -cvalidate'
```

to create an HTML file. Finally, I use Epub compiler to make an epub file (in my case, it's Calibre). And it also worked. But, there are some problems that I ask for help with.

- **Q1**: I don't know what is the best code to do this. Because the code1 will help to compile but it sometimes took a lot of time for a long TeX file. I just wonder whether there is any better code. The code2 seems not to work without using the code1 first (to have a .lg file), but I don't know how and why. Basically, I just use the code1 only.
- **Q2**: When TexStudio generates the HTML file, there are a lot of PNG files describing the formulas. How can I generate a folder to keep all these extra files with the code?
- **Q3**: The inline formula (between `$...$` or `\(...\)`) work well. But the display formula (between `\[...\]` or `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}`, etc.) don't work as expected. How can I fix this?
- **Q4**: When I use `{\color{red} sample text }` to make colour for text and formula, the colour only affects on formula (under PNG) but not the text in HTML. How can I handle coloured text?

Comment: try to compile your file from the command line using `tex4ebook`: `tex4ebook -f epub+dvisvgm_hashes" -m draft filename.tex "svg"`. tex4ebook is variant of `htlatex` that can produce epub file directly.

Answer (score 2):

I find out an idea for my solution as in the following article (link).

By applying the command of that, I solved the questions Q1 and Q3.

For the question Q2, there is a way to set a folder and keep all the images and extra files with `-d,--output-dir`. However, the system also generates the same version of those extra files in the current folder. Thus, there is no way to re-arrange the extra files except deleting manually.

For question Q4, haven't found a solution yet.

[Handling subequations with make4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580400/handling-subequations-with-make4ht)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470290/2891 for a solution for color

Comment: @michal.h21: thank you for your help.